# Decoding a JSON field containing backslash underscore or adding backslash underscore in a string in Elm

Tags: string, functional-programming, elm

So i have a JSON to decode in Elm and one of the fields is `html\_url`

Obviously I get an error if i try like this cause of `"\_"`:

```
Decoder.field "html\_url" Decoder.string
```

I tried

```
Decoder.field "html\\_url" Decoder.string
```

but it checks for field `"html\\_url"` instead of `"html\_url"`

Any idea how can I decode that field? or how can i generate a string like this :

```
"html\_url"
```

Comment: excuse me if it's a stupid question - it's been a long time since I last used Elm - but what's wrong with just `Decoder.field "html_url"`?

Comment: @RobinZigmond nothing wrong with html_url, but i need `html\_url`

Comment: Why? You say yourself that the field is named `html_url`. Seems more likely that you're confusing the actual content of the string with how it's represented in various media.

Comment: Please post the actual JSON. `"html\_url"` is not really valid, it's either `"html_url"` or `"html\\_url"`.